# How to simulate slow and no-read-cache disk drive

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, disk

I need to check my Windows app and see how it works on systems having slow disk.
How can I have a simulated slow disk which Windows doesn't cache it contents so I can repeat my tests?

Update : I have lots of code accessing disk and can't create new classes for simulating slow disc, and portion of code is third party & having no source code accessible.

Update 2 : I need to slow down speed of Directory.GetFiles(), too.

Answer (score 3):

You can create slow [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) over [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) which will do some (or all) operations with delay:

```
public class SlowStream : Stream
{
    private Stream _stream;
    private TimeSpan _delay;

    public SlowStream(Stream stream, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _delay = delay;
    }

    // implementation
}
```

When implementing stream members, you should delegate some operations directly to decorated stream

```
public override bool CanRead 
{
    get { return _stream.CanRead; }
}

public override void Flush() 
{
    _stream.Flush();
}

public override void Close() 
{
    _stream.Close();
}
```

But do delay before other operations, which you want to be slow:

```
public void Wait() 
{
    Thread.Sleep(_delay);
}

public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) 
{
    Wait();
    return _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
}

public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    Wait();
    _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
}
```

Usage:

```
using(var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    var slowStream = new SlowStream(stream, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var reader = new StreamReader(slowStream);
    string line;
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Virtual Machine and throttle disk access ... here are some tips about how do it in Virtualbox 5.8. Limiting bandwidth for disk images https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-bandwidth-limit

I think that MS and VMWare virtualization tools provide similar features.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have the sourcecode you can write a class that emulates the behaviour of the disk and replace all disk reading/writing code with calls to your class.

You need to cache requests done by the application and execute them after some delay.

If you don't have access to the code your hope is to find a driver which emulates a slow disk...ifsuch a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sergey's answer, however in some cases it may be done with less code and without decorator - just inherit from required Stream object and overwrite Read method with delay. Here is the sample class that was enough for my needs in similar situation:

```
    public class SlowStream : MemoryStream
    {
        private readonly TimeSpan _delay;

        public SlowStream(byte[] buffer, TimeSpan delay)
            : base(buffer)
        {
            _delay = delay;
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(_delay);
            return base.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is no different than the other answer, you're just implementing a different base class.